How can i put a placeholder in a sql query string in java?
I need to change the '22-05-2024' with a placeholder to pass dinamically the parameter and then pass the string  to the searchLimit for the query. How can i do? I need to pass the parameter how argument of the method and then...?
Thank you all for the help and sorry for bad english!
I tried to change the date with ? but i don't know if is right
private static final String QUERY_5 = "select * from ESTERO.VW_EST_MARGINI_INVIO_MIDA_Q where 1=1 AND data_riferimento = to_date('22-05-2024','dd-mm-yyyy') and UPCV_CODE = 'UCV_EDCROEETLDFI' and mercato = 'MGP' and data_invio_forecast is not null";

    @Datasource(datasourceKey = EDatasourceKey.DAMASCO)
    public List<UpView> searchLimit()
    {
        try {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            log.debug("call searchLimit(): |{}|", startTime);

            StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder(QUERY_5);

            List<UpView> result = dataAccessService.search(UpView.class, sql.toString(), null, true, true);

            log.info("end searchLimit(): |{}|", System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);

            if(Assorted.notNull(result)) {
                return result;
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return null;
    }


Java JDBC's PreparedStatement allows using SQL statements with parameters. You can use the same statement and supply it with different values each time you execute it.

Some jshell input/output. I hope it will be self-explanatory - say if not:
jshell> private static final String QUERY_5 = "select * from ESTERO.VW_EST_MARGINI_INVIO_MIDA_Q where 1=1 AND data_riferimento = to_date('%s','dd-mm-yyyy') and UPCV_CODE = 'UCV_EDCROEETLDFI' and mercato = 'MGP' and data_invio_forecast is not null";
QUERY_5 ==> "select * from ESTERO.VW_EST_MARGINI_INVIO_MIDA_Q ... nvio_forecast is not null"

jshell> QUERY_5.formatted(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu", Locale.US).format(LocalDate.now()));
$2 ==> "select * from ESTERO.VW_EST_MARGINI_INVIO_MIDA_Q where 1=1 AND data_riferimento = to_date('23-05-2024','dd-mm-yyyy') and UPCV_CODE = 'UCV_EDCROEETLDFI' and mercato = 'MGP' and data_invio_forecast is not null"

The first input line shows your sql adapted by the insertion of a string formatting placeholder.
The second input line shows today's date being formatted by the DateTimeFormatter and used as a parameter to the String::formatted method. You could also use String::format
The last line shows the outcome

DO NOT FOLLOW THIS ADVICE! This kind of code (trying to add dynamic data to SQL using string concatentation or formatting) can end up creating an attack vectors called "SQL injection" which is a top 10 most common security issue! Use a prepared statement instead.

@Torben, I agree and regularly post to that effect on here but that is the nature of the client code given here. There are no java.sql classes in sight. Plus there is no way to pass injection parameters
